# grunt: command not found

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

npm knows that grunt is installed globally, so why isn't it found?

```
$ npm install -g grunt
... installs ...
$ npm list -g | grep grunt
│   ├─┬ gruntfile-editor@0.2.0
│   ├─┬ gruntfile-editor@0.2.0
├─┬ grunt@0.4.5
│ ├─┬ grunt-legacy-log@0.1.1
│ ├── grunt-legacy-util@0.2.0
$ grunt
-bash: grunt: command not found
```

I assume because it's put it somewhere that is not on my PATH.

Why doesn't npm just put it somewhere that is on my PATH by default, like `/usr/local/bin`?

UPDATE: Weirdly, I get the same `grunt: command not found` error even after I do `npm install grunt` to run it locally. What am I doing wrong? There is a `Gruntfile.js` in my repo.

Comment: Oh ffs, it's because I haven't done `npm install -g grunt-cli`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The package "grunt" is the task runner itself whereas the "grunt-cli" package is the command line interface that includes the `grunt` executable. You can make sure that it is installed to the correct path.

If you do `npm install grunt-cli` it still would not work because this would be installed to `node_modules` in the corresponding directory which is most likely not on your path. However, when you use `grunt` from the globally installed CLI tool it will look for an installation of grunt that is local to that project as well as the `Gruntfile.js`

what you have to do is

1. install `grunt-cli` globally:

   $ npm install grunt-cli -g
2. install `grunt` local in your dependencies (optionally save the dependency to your package.json):

   $ npm install grunt --save

Answer (score 2):

For me there was another thing missing, adding the path to NPM's folder in Window's env variables

- Go to System (My computer->Properties)
- Advanced System Settings
- In Advanced tab, 'Environment Variables'
- Under User variables, choose Path, then Edit
- Add this alongside the others you have: '%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm'

Hope this helps, g'luck